# Join/Merge two pandas dataframes and filling

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes both holding irregular timeseries data.

I want merge/join the two frames by time.

I also want to forward fill the other columns of frame2 for any "new" rows that were added through the joining process. How can I do this?

I have tried:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on="DateTime")
```

but this just leave a frame with matching timestamp rows.

I would be grateful for any ideas!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this.  The `how='left'` will have the merge keep all records of df1, and the `fillna` will populate missing values.

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='DateTime', how='left').fillna(method='ffill')
```

Comment: Will it also keep all the values of df2?

Comment: If you want the union of keys (i.e. both df1 and df1), use `how='outer'`

Comment: Is the `fillna` necessary? Isn't this the default behavior of a left join?

Comment: default behavior of left join is to fill it with `NaN`s

Comment: shorter: ```df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='DateTime', how='left').ffill()```

Answer (score 0):

Left join then fillna doesn't fully utilize the data in `right`. We usually expect ffill from the most recent data of the `right`.

See that we get full of NaNs in the below although `df2` has data on 2, 4, and 6 which can be good approximate of its value on 3, 5, and 7.

```
In [47]: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 3, 5, 7]}, index=[1, 3, 5, 7])
    ...: df2 = pd.DataFrame({'b': [2, 4, 6, 8]}, index=[2, 4, 6, 8])

In [48]: pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True).ffill()
Out[48]: 
   a   b
1  1 NaN
3  3 NaN
5  5 NaN
7  7 NaN
```

Instead, ffill first and then join. See that we're getting the data from the most recent date of the df2.

```
In [50]: new_df2 = df2.reindex(df1.index, method='ffill')

In [51]: new_df2
Out[51]: 
     b
1  NaN
3  2.0
5  4.0
7  6.0
```

And then join:

```
In [52]: pd.merge(df1, new_df2, how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)
Out[52]: 
   a    b
1  1  NaN
3  3  2.0
5  5  4.0
7  7  6.0
```